# Add a div with width occupying space between multiple floating divs

Tags: html, word-wrap

what's the best way to set html so that divs wont get to the next line on resizing the browser window? 
*if width is set in percentage and min width is given to each div, it doesen't work.

[`Demo fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/rvrjp7/6zyrxotb/)

Comment: An empty JSFiddle isn't much use. Please add your code _within_ your question using a [StackSnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rvrjp7/6zyrxotb/ trying to insert link in the post but giving error.

Comment: Read the error then, don't just ignore it - i.e. the error says you cannot just post a link to fiddle, the code **must** be included in the question too

Comment: Ok then ignore it and our comments, good luck with getting any help

Answer (score 0):

you can use calc function of css
`width: calc( 100% - 70px );`

100% is total width of the parent
70px is 20px div * 3 + its border and padding

this will work until other 3 div have fixed width

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8d90xcL/)

Comment: yes if width is fixed it will work. but i want to keep second div (id="left2") as responsive with some minimum width.